# Python / Strings / Consonants

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my head around, how to get a representation of consonants in a sentence. 
Code I'm using just now doesn't seem to do the job:

```
vowels = ("aeiou")
count = 0
for x in text:
    if not x in vowels:
        count += 1
```

In example " hello world " as an input, I receive 8 consonants. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting all characters including spaces. In addition you would want to include punctuation, spaces and any other non-consonant characters.

Answer (score 9):

You're better off checking for consonants directly, rather than 'not vowels and not whitespace and not punctuation and...'

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
count = 0
for x in text:
    if x in consonants:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Yuck, you don't need to copy the () around the "" from the OP! But +1 anyway, better to have a whitelist of what you are counting

Answer (score 4):

More directly

```
consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
count = sum(1 for c in text if c in consonants)
```

Using a set for the consonants should make the lookup a little faster

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

all_letters = string.ascii_letters

consonants = set(all_letters).difference(set(('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')))

my_sentence = 'Here is my Sentence'

sum_of_cons = sum(ele in consonants for ele in my_sentence)
```

Result

```
>>> sum_of_cons
10
```

Answer (score 1):

If speed does come into play, a compiled regular expression appears to be the fastest way to get the count.

**Timing Results**

```
Found 8292 Consonants in 0.002978 seconds using compiled regex
Found 8292 Consonants in 0.009412 seconds using sets
Found 8292 Consonants in 0.024511 seconds by looking at each character
```

**Test Code**

```
import re
import time
import os
string_length = 100000
random_string = os.urandom(string_length)

con_re = re.compile("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]")
start = time.clock()
re_results = con_re.findall(random_string)
print "Found %d Consonants in %f seconds using compiled regex" % (len(re_results), time.clock() - start)

consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
start = time.clock()
count = sum(1 for c in random_string if c in consonants)
print "Found %d Consonants in %f seconds using sets" % (count, time.clock() - start)

cnt = 0
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
start = time.clock()
for x in range(string_length):
    if random_string[x] in consonants:
        cnt += 1
print "Found %d Consonants in %f seconds by looking at each character" % (cnt, time.clock() - start)
```

Comment: Nice analysis. I extended these tests to cover 1000 strings of length 100 and the results were almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to account for whitespace.

8 looks like the correct answer based on your code.

The space character is not in your vowel list.

Comment: Thank you guys I've added new characters into my variable now it seems to do just fine !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code:

```
consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
word=" hello world "
number_of_consonants = sum(word.count(c) for c in consonants)
```

Comment: your consonants are broken :)

Comment: consonants does not have to be converted to a list. It can just be string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solutions using conditions for *non-vowels*, a *dictionary comprehension* and a *`Counter`*.

```
import collections as ct

text = "Hello world!"
vowels = ("aeiou")
letters = ct.Counter(text.lower())
```

For similar techniques previously shown, having a long list of consonants is not necessary.  You can still search for letters that are not vowels using  `isalpha` and `not in vowels`.  `isalpha` eliminates spaces and punctuation:

```
# Option 1: Non-vowels

sum(1 for letter in text.lower() if letter.isalpha() and not letter in vowels)
 # 7
```

For finer details, we can use a `Counter` object to tally each unique letter in the text and a dictionary comprehension to keep all the consonants:

```
# Option 2: Dictionary comprehension

comp = {k:v for k, v in letters.items() if letter.isalpha() and not letter in vowels}    
comp 
# {'d': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 3, 'r': 1, 'w': 1}

sum(comp.values())
# 7
```

Furthermore, `Counter` objects have helpful attributes such as `.most_common()` and `.elements()`.  You can of course also total all consonants easily.  Here we will make a special `Counter` for consonants alone:

```
# Option 3: Consonants counter

consonants = letters.copy()
for k in letters:
    if k in vowels or not k.isalpha():
        consonants.pop(k)

consonants
# Counter({'d': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 3, 'r': 1, 'w': 1})

consonants.most_common(3)
#[('l', 3), ('d', 1), ('h', 1)] 

list(consonants.elements())
# ['d', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'r', 'w']

sum(consonants.values())
# 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_consonants(sample_string):
    spaces_removed = sample_string.replace(" ", "")
    count = 0
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for char in spaces_removed.lower():
        if char not in vowels:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, make sure to include an explanation how and why your code solves the problem of the question. Also, when answering, consider that this is a nearly 7 year old question with 9 other answers: your question must bring something really new or a higher quality than existing questions. It might be better to answer more recent and unanswered questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_consonants(some_string):
    some_string=some_string.lower();
    consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
    number_of_consonants = sum(some_string.count(c) for c in consonants)
    return number_of_consonants

test_str="Hercules was a hero"
result_str=count_consonants(test_str)
print(result_str)
```